# Assigning a meta_query value based on regexp to wp_query fails

Tags: wp-query, search

I have a text that is submitted to search on a wordpress site: "text123". 
From this text I would like to extract a number consisting of 3 digits (123) and search for the post that has a 'key' = 'offer' and a value of this key equals to the 3 digit number extracted from the search text (in this case '123'). 
I cannot get it to work with the following code:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/',get_query_var( 's' ), $matches);
$off = $matches[0];

$meta_query = 
    array(
        'key' => 'offer',
        'value' => $off,
        'compare' => '='
    );
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

The $query seems to be just ignoring the 'meta_query' and returns the results that contain the whole searched text ("text123").

When I assign a value like this:

```
$query->set('posts_per_page', '4');
```

it works fine and only 4 posts are displayed in search results. But with meta_query it has no effect on $query what so ever.

Does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: If you're inside the `pre_get_posts` filter, can you not use `$query->get('s')` instead of `get_query_var`? I'm assuming this is inside that filter. Also keep in mind that your `offer` post meta should be stored as a taxonomy named `offers` instead, it would be significantly faster in every way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta query should be an array of arrays (every array contains one condition).

So instead of

```
$meta_query = 
    array(
        'key' => 'offer',
        'value' => $off,
        'compare' => '='
    );
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

There should be

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'offer',
        'value' => $off,
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

PS. It would be a good idea to check if `preg_match` returns true - if there is no match, your code won’t make much sense, I guess ;)